# Как подключить хедер из папки решения?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть решение, есть 2 проекта в нем. В решении лежат 2 хедера. Мне нужно подключить хедер Key.h в main.cpp (в проекте "Builder"). Но, когда пытаюсь подключить его через #include, он не видит эти .h-файлы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже, что Вам нужно указать `#include "../Project7/Key.h"`

Comment: покажите структуру папок